# Two isomorphism questions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G = (C - {0}, mult.), and let U be the subgroup U = {x+yi such that x^2 + y^2 = 1}. Use the Fundamental Theorem to show that:

a) G/U is isomorphic to (R>0, mult.)

b) G/R>0 is isomorphic to U.

So to prove something is isomorphic we have to show that the operation is preserved as well as one-to-one, and onto. Can anyone help me with these two?

Comment: A hint for part $(a)$ is to consider the map $f : \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ defined by $f(z) = |z|$.  What is the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Show that the functions $f:\mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{>0}}$ given by $f(z) = |z|$ and $g:\mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ given by $\displaystyle g(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$ are homomorphisms, find their kernels and images, and apply the first isomorphism theorem.